# iOS - Not allocating too much memory at once

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiview

Trying to get around a crash that is happening on some iOS devices, in conjunction with advice from Apple to "not cause allocation spikes". How can I change this code to not happen all at once?

```
for (Item *item in self.items) {
        ItemView *itemView = [[ItemView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, kYItemOffsetIphone, kItemWidthIphone, kItemHeightIphone) ];

        itemView.delegate = self;
        [itemView layoutWithData:item]; //this just adds an imageView and button
        [self.scrollView addSubview:itemView];
        xPos += kXItemSpacingIphone;
    }
```

There are around 20 objects in the self.items array, which are used to build the 20 ItemViews. Again, is there some way to make this code less "allocation intensive"?

Comment: Are all the views visible at the same time? If not, you could defer creating a view until it's about to go on-screen (and, similarly, you could destroy a view when it goes offscreen [as long as you can re-create its current state later]). This is how `UITableView` works.

Comment: @KevinBallard is there boilerplate code for doing that with a UIScrollView?

Comment: @soleil so what you essentially want is a `UITableView` but rotated by 90 degrees?

Comment: @Tommy yes, I guess you could say that. It's just a scrollview of images.

Comment: @soleil perhaps a Collection View might help? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

I personally do something along the lines of:

1. Make my view controller the `delegate` of the scroll view (if you do this in code, you have to modify your view controller's .h to say that it conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`).
2. Define a [`scrollViewDidScroll`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) method that (a) determines the frame of the visible portion of the scroll view; (b) determine which of the subviews intersect with that visible portion; (c) load the items that are visible, and unload the ones that aren't.

So, for example, it might look something like the following:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Determine the frame of the visible portion of the scrollview.

    CGRect visibleScrollViewFrame = scrollView.bounds;
    visibleScrollViewFrame.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;

    // Now iterate through the various items, remove the ones that are not visible,
    // and show the ones that are.

    for (Item *itemObject in self.itemCollection)
    {
        // Determine the frame within the scrollview that the object does (or 
        // should) occupy.

        CGRect itemObjectFrame = [self getItemObjectFrame:itemObject];

        // see if those two frames intersect

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleScrollViewFrame, itemObjectFrame))
        {
            // If it's visible, then load it (if it's not already).
            // Personally, I have my object have a boolean property that
            // tells me whether it's loaded or not. You can do this any
            // way you want.

            if (!itemObject.loaded)
                [itemObject loadItem];
        }
        else
        {
            // If not, go ahead and unload it (if it's loaded) to conserve memory.

            if (itemObject.loaded)
                [itemObject unloadItem];
        }
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea. You can certainly optimize this logic based upon your app's particular design, but this is how I generally do it.

Comment: Great answer. The asker might also implement some sort of reusable view array so that as items are moved off-screen they are removed from the view hierarchy and added to this reusable views array. When a new item is being loaded, the code can check to see if there is a reusable view already created, if so, get a reference to the reusable view and then remove it from the array. Rinse and repeat. This is very similar to how instances of `UITableView` manage their cells in very long lists with lots of views.

Comment: @ThuggishNuggets Agreed. I was trying to keep it simple, but you're quite right. (This dequeuing logic probably belongs in these `loadItem` and `unloadItem` methods.) For optimal performance, he might also want to do some caching of the images, themselves (I subclass `NSCache`). It's annoying when at the end of the scrollview and it bounces back to get a little delay in the re-retrieval of the image. But again, I was trying to keep it simple.